# wrong parameters for function remap

Tags: c++, function, opencv, arguments, signature

I have the following opencv code:

```
InputArray fish =InputArray(ra);
InputArray base =  InputArray(ra);

 Mat warp(Mat input) {
    if (!f) {
        fish = genfish(input);
        f = true
    }
    if (!b) {
        base = bladArray;
        b = true
    }
    Mat ret;
    InputArray i = InputArray(input);
    OutputArray p;

    remap(i, p, fish, bladArray, 0, BORDER_CONSTANT, Scalar());
}
```

The idea behind this code is applying the fish eye correction efficiently on the image (that's why the filter is buffered). The problem is that appently I'm passing the wrong arguments to the remap function. According to the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/opencv2refman.pdf) (page 273) we have the following signature:

```
void remap ( InputArray src , OutputArray dst , InputArray map1, InputArray map2 , int interpolation , int borderMode =BORDER_CONSTANT, const Scalar& borderValue =Scalar() )
```

now

```
InputArray src = i 
OutputArray dst= p
InputArray map1=fish
InputArray map2=bladarray
int interpolation=0
int bordermode=BORDER_CONSTANT
Scaler borderValue=scaler();
```

which all seems to fit the signature yet it keeps telling me I have the wrong signature. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: use cv::Mat for args , not InputArray or OutputArray

Comment: tried that as well but didn't work either or do you mean by switching all of them?

Comment: obviously. that's why you tried it this way. still, go back to cv::Mat and try again.

Comment: Mat input,fish,bladArray; Mat output; remap(input,output,fish,bladArray,0) ;

Comment: thank you should have put the fish and bladArray into mats as well